# How to make a query on multiple columns without writting all possible permutations?

Tags: oracle, performance, plsql, execution-plan

I'm at my first question on stackexchange, as i have a few days since I struggle on this matter:

I want to make a complex query(PLSQL) on a table that has col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 having values like (names: which are split- one part per column)

- Andrew Joan Bach Mike
- Mark Andrew Livy
- Joan Arch Donnie
- Joan Andrew Lyx

Number of parts differ from 1 to 5.

I want to search in different combinations like this:

1. **Bach Joan Mike** - get #1, #3,#4 order
2. **Andrew Bach** - get the following order #1,#2,#4 order

I don't like the idea of using a looooong query in which I will write all possible permutations in order to mach each part of my search string

What I'd like to achieve is this:

1. **first set**: match all those n parts (both **Bach** and **Joan** and **Bach** match, in any order)
2. **second set**: match n-1 parts (at least N-1 of my search parts match the row, in any order)
3. **third set**: match n-2 parts

I use a ORACLE database and I was thinking on making it in a stored procedure: match_my_set(query_str,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5). I would write at least 5 loops (loop into loop) in order to achieve this, but I doubt it is a professional idea . .

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You don't need loops, but one CASE per searched value:

```
select ...
from
 ( 
   select ...
      case when 'Bach' IN (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) then 1 else 0 end +
      case when 'Joan' IN (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) then 1 else 0 end +
      case when 'Mike' IN (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) then 1 else 0 end as matches
   from tab
 ) dt
where matches > 0
order by matches desc
```

Comment: That is a great one! Brilliant! Thank you